# MySQL sorting: how to make Cyrillic characters go before Latin characters?

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, collation

I'm using MySQL to store Cyrillic and Latin strings. I want to display all these strings in a list, sorted alphabetically. However, they are currently sorted according to the first character like that:

1. Numbers
2. Latin characters
3. Cyrillic characters

I'd like Cyrillic characters to go before Latin characters. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things efficient, I think the best way would be to [create a custom collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-collation.html).

Comment: Can I create it if I don't have access to the MySQL server?

Comment: @exizt: Unfortunately no, as you'll have to modify the server's character set configuration files.